# How do I center images in team section of my website

Tags: html, css, image, center

I am trying to center images in team section of my website. I have three images with text underneath them and would want the center image to be in the center of the browser on PC, phone, ipad, etc. I have the responsive packet built just need to adjust the css and html code.

Here is what I have right now:

```css
.featured-images {
  padding: 55px 0;
  background: #f9b701;
  text-align: center;
}

.featured-images h1 {
  font-size: 44px;
  color: #2d6e84;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'fjalla_oneregular';
}

.featured-images h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 34px;
  color: #2d6e84;
  font-family: 'source_sans_prolight';
}

.featured-images .hh-divider {
  background: url(../img/hh-divider.png) repeat-x 50%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 7px;
}

.featured-images .grid li .user-info ul {
  margin-top: 15px !important;
}

.featured-images .grid li .user-info ul li {
  width: 16%;
  float: none !important;
}

.featured-images .grid li .user-info ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.featured-images .grid li .user-info {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.featured-images .user-info img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.featured-images .user-info h1 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #2a363c;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-family: 'fjalla_oneregular';
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.featured-images .user-info p {
  color: #44535a;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-family: 'source_sans_proregular';
  text-align: center;
}

.featured-images .user-info ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.featured-images .user-info ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.featured-images .user-info ul li [class^="fw-icon-"] {
  border-radius: 23px;
  color: #f9b701;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: inline-block !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 14px !important;
  height: 14px !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: none;
  padding: 6px;
  background: #2d6e84;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.featured-images .user-info ul li [class^="fw-icon-"]:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #fff;
  color: #2d6e84;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-images">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>OUR TEAM</h1>
    <h2>MEET OUR TEAM</h2>
    <div class="hh-divider"></div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <ul class="grid effect-3" id="grid">
        <!--##############################################################TEAM MEMBERS#########################################################################-->
        <li class="span2">
          <div class="user-info">
            <div class="aligncenter">
              <img src="img/sam.jpeg" alt="">
              <h1>name1 </h1>
              <p class="last">Co-president </br> MBA 2018 </p>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fw-icon-facebook"></a></i>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fw-icon-twitter"></a></i>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span2">
          <div class="user-info">
            <div class="aligncenter">
              <img src="img/sam.jpeg" alt="">
              <h1>name2 </h1>
              <p class="last">Co-president </br> MBA 2018 </p>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fw-icon-facebook"></a></i>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fw-icon-twitter"></a></i>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span2">
          <div class="user-info">
            <div class="aligncenter">
              <img src="img/sam.jpeg" alt="">
              <h1>name3 </h1>
              <p class="last">Co-president </br> MBA 2018 </p>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fw-icon-facebook"></a></i>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fw-icon-twitter"></a></i>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: That CSS isn't great, and what's with the excessive `#` in the HTML comments?

Comment: @cybermonkey It seems like the comments make the `.html` file seem more orgainized.

Comment: @lejanp It looks pretty good to me. You just need to remove the padding from the `ul` and possibly `li` element.

Comment: @ChrisHappy Yes, but there really isn't any need for excessive `#`, especially when seeking help on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry about that guys

Answer (score 1):

Start by getting rid of the padding and list markers in your overall `ul`. Then, set the items in the list to display inline. You may need to adjust the spacing of the items with margin and padding after that.

```css
ul.grid {
  padding-left:0px;
  list-style-type:none;
}

ul.grid li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Depending on the browsers you need to support, you could really have fun and get into some CSS Grid. Take a look at the docs for the [CSS display property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

Last, as a commenter mentioned, it would be nice to clean up your CSS selectors a little bit. I know we're not seeing the whole page here, but this looks like a lot of unnecessary qualifications.

EDIT: The overqualified selectors impact the selectors in my example above. You can either simplify some of the selectors you are already using or add `!important` to some of the declarations. (This isn't really a great way to work, but it will be functional, and there are a lot of other problems with this code you'd want to fix first.)

Comment: thanks for this! the problem seems to be in the featured-images.user-info part. I did it the way you suggested and it still indents the images to the left.